# How to display waiter while resolving data in Angular 2.0.0?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, router, angular2-routing

I've project based on Angular 2.0.0, and I want to display waiter (gif or text) while navigating routes, which must resolve data like this:

```
   { 
      path: 'profile',
      loadChildren: () => System.import('../profile/profile.module'),
      resolve: {
        profile: ProfileResolver
      },
    },
```

Also, preloader need to be applied to every route in project.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you can create a service which would keep eye on routing events and based on `NavigationStart` & `NavigationEnd` event it will `show/hide` loading based on `isLoading` flag value with combination of `[hidden]`.

**Code**

```
isLoading: bool = false;
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
       this.isLoading = true;
    }
    if(event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError) {
       this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I need to inject this service in every component, and wrap `<router-outlet>` with something sensitive to `service.isLoading`?

Comment: You forgot to add ` || event instanceof NavigationEnd` in your code example. Also, thanks, I've injected this service with some improvements into root component and wrap `<router-outlet>` with `[hidden]` directive.

Comment: @Ivan sorry I was trying to create a demo, but I didn't succeed in it, Though thanks :-)